# Can't execute "swift test" in non-XCode Swift project

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code, xctest

I'm beginning in Swift development (server side, no iOS). I have created the minimal package with `swift package init` and then `swift build`.

So far, so good. Now, when I run `swift test`, I get this error:

> cannot load underlying module for 'XCTest'

I'm not using XCode, but just Visual Studio Code. How can I solve it? I have seen some solutions using XCode but I didn't found anything for "standalone" projects

Comment: Even if you're not using Xcode's editor, you still need the tools that come with it. Do you have Xcode installed and up-to-date?

Comment: Add more tags related to your question, because otherwise you don't get as much attention.

Comment: @Jerry I have installed updated Xcode components and it's working now. Thank you! I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're not using Xcode's editor, you still need the tools that come with it. Make sure you keep everything up-to-date, as the language is still evolving.